# How to Write Matrix A(:,1) from Matlab in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, matlab

I want to write matrix from MATLAB in C# using Matlab Application Reference 
MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();

Matlab Code:
freqmag(:,2) = abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1));

because matlab only give short example : https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-c-client.html
i have no idea how to do it?

Comment: Pass everything like you would from c# to c++ in a parameter list.  So you would have a method in Matlab : MyFFT(*double) where freqmag would be returned by reference to c#.  In c# then matlab.Feval("MyFFT", out freqmag);  You would then use : IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((NFFT / 2 + 1) * sizeof(double));

Comment: my concern that i can make matrix like matlab in c# (column and row). is there any command, or i should make regular array of array. ie. freqmag[1][2] that mean row 1 column 2 freqmag?

Comment: You have to move the data from unmanaged to managed space so you want to make sure the sizes of the data objects is know.  You also have to remember strings in Matlab are c language being byte[] terminated with '\0'.  In c# characters are two by class objects.  So you may want to return an array of structure.  See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-structure-array.html